# .Net Core 3.0のPublish時に、参照しているDLLのPDBファイルも一緒にPublishする方法

Tags: c#, visual-studio, .net-core

.Net Core 3.0でPublishして一つのExeにまとめた時、そのプロジェクトのExeとPDBファイルは出力されるのですが、参照先のDLLのPDBファイルなどは出力されません。なので、Debug時のエラー発生時に詳細な情報を取得できなくて困っています。
通常のBuildなどで出力されたPDBファイルを手動で持ってこれば解決できるのですが、Publishで自動的に参照しているDLLのPDBファイルも同時に出力する方法はありませんか？
Visual Studioは2019を使用しています。

Comment: この辺の記事が関連していそうですが、まだ対策中ですかね？ [New project system doesn't copy PDBs from packages #1458](https://github.com/dotnet/sdk/issues/1458), [dotnet core 3.0 doesn't copy symbol files(*.pdb) and xml document files from nuget package to bin/publish folder. #3587](https://github.com/dotnet/core/issues/3587), [PDB files are not copied from package lib folder to the consumer bin folder #1383](https://github.com/dotnet/sdk/issues/1383)

Comment: 対策中です！情報ありがとうございます！リンク先を見て試してみます。

Comment: 未だに修正されていないみたいです。とりあえずは、pdbファイルを展開先に手動で置いてしばらくは暫定処置で対応します。回答ありがとうございました。